# vb.net and asp.net Mapping options

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm currently exploring a transport solution where my user will map a route for a driver,
I have everything almost there and have a gridview of data with upto 25 drops, I would like to give him a visual aid that where he can see the run

does google / bing / other have anything I can drop into my solution and populate post codes and it map the drivers route visibly ?

Comment: Yes to all three. It's not that trivial though. Both cloud providers offer mapping APIs with geolocation and so do a lot of other providers. You'll have to check each one to see what they offer, what the API looks like and how to integrate with your project.

Comment: The GMap nuget package is relatively simple to use, and can be set to use several different map sources like google and others. It even has some free map sources in it as well, and there are some good examples online on how to get a map shown and adding markers to it